# In two different partial Want to pass two variable

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `show.html.erb` file  for user
here i add partial file a details as `_details.html.erb`
in detail page i have partial as `_form.html.erb`

Now i did code like this.Have partial file code in `show.html.erb`

```
user
@user_entry

<%= render :partial => "users/details" ,:locals => {:user => user } %>
```

have partial file code  in `_detail.html.erb`

```
<%= render :partial => "users/form" %>
```

I have this two `user & @user_entry` i want `@user_entry` variable in `form`  partial how can i ?

help me if anyone know

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this.
in your `show.html.erb`

```
User
@user_entry

<%= render :partial => "users/details" ,:locals => {:user => user,:user_entry => @user_entry } %>
```

and than try to access `user_entry` variable in you `_details.html.erb`
file.

Answer (score 4):

Instance variables (those with the `@` sign in front) are available in all partials, when they are defined before the render call.

When you pass `locals`, then they are available as local variables and are not "forwarded" to subsequent partials.

**Controller:**

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.all
  end
end
```

**foos/index.html.erb**

```
Template: we have <%= @foos.count %>
<%= render('partial', locals: {foos: @foos, other: 'a value here'}) %>
```

**foos/_partial.html.erb**

```
Partial: We have <%= foos.count %> and <%= other %>
<%= render('subpartial', locals: {foos: foos, other: 'another value here'}) %>
```

**foos/_subpartial.html.erb**

```
Subpartial: We have <%= foos.count %> and <%= other %>
```